# Как создать экземпляр класса по его конструктору?

Tags: php, ооп, классы, рефлексия

есть следующий код:

```
class Logger
{
    public function __construct(Config $config)
    {
        $this->mode = $config->get('logger.mode');
    }
}

class DB
{

    public function connect($dbUser, $dbPass)
    {

    }

}

class TodoService
{

    public function __construct(
        TodoListHelper $todoHelper,
        ItemHelper $itemHelper
    )
    {
        $this->todoHelper = $todoHelper;
        $this->itemHelper = $itemHelper;
    }

}
```

Далее есть метод autoMake, как с помощью метода можно создать экземпляр ?

```
public function autoMake($contract)
    {
        $getDependencies = function ($contract) {

        };

        $deps = $getDependencies($contract);


        return new $contract($deps);
    }
```

Comment: Экземпляр чего?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы с помощью метода autoMake($contract) создать екземпляр нужно его поместить в класс

```
class autoMake
{
    private $contract;

    public function __construct($contract)
    {
        $this->contract = $contract;
    }

    public function autoMake()
    {
        $getDependencies = function ($contract) {

        };

        $deps = $getDependencies($contract);


        return new $contract($deps);
    }
}
```

Екземпляр класу

```
$autoMake = new autoMake(//передаєм контракт);
echo $autoMake->autoMake();
```

Comment: Насчет класса согласен, но разве нам не нужно с помощью Reflection(если не путаю)  создать экземпляр ? А потом  с помощью make() возвращать экземпляр ?

Comment: public function make($contract)
    {
        if (!isset($this->instances[$contract])) {

            if (isset($this->callbacks[$contract])) {
                $callback = $this->callbacks[$contract];
                $this->instances[$contract] = $callback($this);
            } else {
                $this->instances[$contract] = $this->autoMake($contract);
            }

        }
        return $this->instances[$contract];
    }